# Questions to the virial theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

Let $H = H_0 + V$ be the Hamiltonian of the single electron where $H_0 = - \Delta, V = - \frac{\gamma}{|x|}$.
Now one defines the dilation group
$U(s) \psi(x) = e^{-ns/2} \psi(e^{-s}x), s \in \mathbb R$.
My questions:

1) What is the motivation for the exact definition of $U$?

2) How does one compute the infitesimal generator of $U$? This should be $D = 1/2(x\cdot p + p \cdot x)$.

3) Why does the action of $U$ on $V$ equal $e^{-s}V$, that is, why is
$U(-s)VU(s) = e^{-s}V$?

4) The virial theorem now asserts that an eigenfunction $\psi$ of $H$
 satisfies $-\langle \psi, H_0, \psi \rangle = \langle \psi, V \psi\rangle$.
What does change if $V$ satisfies $U(-s)VU(s) = e^{-\alpha s}V$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}?$

Comment: What is your $n$ here ? Is it a global constant ? I would be surprised that this $n$ does not appears in $D$.

Comment: Ah, this $n$ is the dimension of the  $\mathbb R^n$ the functions live in. So it is probably the Hamiltonian of one particle, so the $n$ is contained implicitely in $D = 1/2(x\cdot p + p \cdot x) = (x \cdot p - \frac{i n}{2})$

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you worked in $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, it won't change a lot. Let us  go step by step then : first, to compute $D$, try using the definition : $U(\epsilon)\psi=\psi+i\epsilon D (\psi) + O(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: Hm, $D$ is given as the derivative $D \psi = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{1}{s}(U(s) \psi - \psi) = \lim \frac{1}{s} (e^{-ns/2} \psi(e^{-s}x) - \psi(x))$, which i dont see how to compute.

Comment: Let's say that we define the operator $C$ by $U(s)\psi=is C(\psi)+O(s^2)$. Can you inject this in your definition of $D$ to have $D=C$ ?

Comment: Antoher way to see, can you write $e^{-ns/2}\psi(e^{-s}x)$ as $\psi(x)+s\chi(x)+O(s^2)$ ?